# switch statement always goes to default in javascript

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I want to do a simple program that prints out different phrases depending on whether a specific condition is met. We input 2 integer parameters in a function and it evaluates whether one number is greater, less than, or whether both numbers are equal to each other. My code looks like this:

```
function CheckNums(num1,num2) {
switch (num1,num2) {
  case (num2>num1):
   console.log('num2 greater than num1');
   break;
  case (num2 === num1):
   console.log('both equal');
   break;
  default:
   console.log('num1 greater than num2');
  }
}
```

Either case, whether I input: CheckNums(4,5) , CheckNums(2,2) , CheckNums(5,4) the program runs default.

**IMPORTANT:** Im not asking for an alternative solution to this problem. I already managed to solve it using if statements or the ternary operator. What I'm asking is: *WHY IS THIS SWITCH NOT WORKING?*

**Questions that I`ve consulted that didn't solve my problem:**

[JavaScript switch statement only executes the default case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267645/javascript-switch-statement-only-executes-the-default-case?rq=1)

The sol:This guy had a problem where the Math.random() generator only generated numbers with decimal places, which of course, wouldn't go to either case except default.

[JS Switch case not working correctly always default is executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848036/js-switch-case-not-working-correctly-always-default-is-executed)

The sol:This guy was inputing strings as a parameter, and was expecting int values in the cases.

**Other notes:**

-Maybe the answer lies on using parseint? (Assuming that the parameters are not being inputed as ints.)

-I removed the parenthesis that go in the cases. That didn't solve my problem.

-For the second case, I also experimented using equality operator(==) instead of the Identity operator (===). The second case still did not work.

**My best guess for where the problem is hiding:**
When I compiled the program in google chrome console, I get the following notification: "undefined". So, I think that's whats not allowing my cases to evaluate the parameters properly. Something is not being defined properly.

Comment: You can only switch 1 expression.  And the case lines have to be some value, not an expression.

Comment: You are using the switch statement wrongly. With switch statements, you test for different values, not conditions.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use a switch statement to do that you'll have to be clever.  Hint:  an IF is way easier.

```js
function CheckNums(num1, num2) {
  switch (Math.sign(num1 - num2)) {
  case -1:
   console.log('num2 greater than num1');
   break;
  case 0:
   console.log('both equal');
   break;
  case 1:
   console.log('num1 greater than num2');
   break;
  default:
   console.log('Something went wrong');
   break;
  }
}

CheckNums(8, 5);
CheckNums(3, 4);
CheckNums(10, 10);
CheckNums("argh", "argh");
```

Answer (score 1):

> WHY IS THIS SWITCH NOT WORKING?

Because what you have written is equivalent to

```
const temp = num1,num2; // comma operator evaluates to the second operand
if (temp === (num2>num1)) {
   console.log('num2 greater than num1');
} else if (temp === (num2 === num1)) {
   console.log('both equal');
} else {
   console.log('num1 greater than num2');
}
```

You're comparing a number to booleans, which is never true, so given none of the cases match the `default` is executed.

Answer (score 0):

An explanation as to why it does not work is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312817/javascript-switch-with-logical-operators). This is to do with how the switch actually works.

Here is the modified code that works:

```js
function CheckNums(num1, num2) {
  switch (true) {
    case num2 > num1:
      console.log("num2 greater than num1");
      break;
    case num2 === num1:
      console.log("both equal");
      break;
    default:
      console.log("num1 greater than num2");
  }
}

CheckNums(5, 6);
```